# how to get count items that not exists for user with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `user_item`

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | item_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       |
| 2  | 1       | 3       |
| 3  | 2       | 1       |
| 4  | 2       | 2       |
| 5  | 3       | 2       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Is it possible to get for each user (except user_id 1) number of items that user_id 1 has and other users don't. The desired output should be:

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | count |
+---------+-------+
| 2       | 1     |
| 3       | 2     |
+---------+-------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: What if a user has NO items at all? Do you have a separate table with users so that we could at least know their id?

Comment: Also are we talking about MySql, Sql Server, Oracle, Postgre...?

Comment: Can one user have the same item multiple times?

Comment: 1. yes - table `user`. 2. it's MySql. 3. no.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . This is tricky.  Let's start by getting the count that match user 1.  Assuming user/item pairs are not duplicated:

```
select ui.user_id, count(ui1.item_id) as match_user_1
from user_items ui left join
     user_items ui1
     on ui1.item_id = ui.item_id and
        ui1.user_id = 1
group by ui.user_id;
```

Now, let's subtract from the total number of items that the user has:

```
select ui.user_id, count(*) - count(ui1.item_id) as not_match_user_1
from user_items ui left join
     user_items ui1
     on ui1.item_id = ui.item_id and
        ui1.user_id = 1
group by ui.user_id;
```

EDIT:

For the reverse, it is pretty much the same idea, but you need to subtract the matches from the total for user 1:

```
select ui.user_id, count(ui1.item_id) as match_user_1,
       uuix.cnt - count(ui1.item_id) as not_match_user_1
from user_items ui cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from user_items
      where user_id = 1
     ) ui1x left join
     user_items ui1
     on ui1.item_id = ui.item_id and
        ui1.user_id = 1
group by ui.user_id;
```

Comment: I've just changed `count(ui.item_id)` to `count(ui1.item_id)`.

Comment: Hmm... Wait, this returns the other way round. This calculates how many items user X has that user 1 doesn't; what the OP asked for was how many items user 1 has, that user X doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68447473/41360), here's my take:

```
select
    u.id,
    count(*) - count(ui.item_id) cnt
from
    users u
    join user_items ui1 on ui.id=1
    left join user_items ui on ui.user_id=u.id and ui.item_id=ui1.item_id
where
    u.id <>1
group by
    u.id
```

We start by taking each user except the one with `id=1`. Then we multiply each row by each item for user with `id=1`. Then to each of the resulting rows we try to join the row for the same item of the other user. Then we group them together and count. The total `count(*)` will always be the number of items that user with `id=1` has. The `count(ui.item_id)` will be the count of items that both users have overlapping. And the difference is the count of items that user with `id=1` has that the other user doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the table and populating the table with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE user_item
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id int,
    item_id int
);

INSERT INTO user_item VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,2,1),(4,2,2),(5,3,2);
```

The below query displays the number of items of user_id 1 that other users don't have.

```
SELECT ui.user_id, (select count(item_id) - count(ui1.item_id) from user_item where user_id = 1) as count
  FROM user_item UI
       LEFT JOIN user_item ui1 ON ui1.item_id = ui.item_id AND ui1.user_id = 1
 WHERE ui.user_id <> 1
 GROUP BY ui.user_id
 ORDER BY ui.user_id;
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | count |
+---------+-------+
| 2       | 1     |
+---------+-------+
| 3       | 2     |
+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too..

```
select u2.user_id, (T.counter - COALESCE(SUM(u1.item_id), 0))counter
From user_item u2
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, item_id
    FROM user_item
    WHERE user_id=1
)u1 ON u2.item_id=u1.item_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(1)counter FROM user_item where user_id=1 group by user_id
)T ON u2.user_id != T.user_id
where u2.user_id!=1
Group by u2.user_id,T.counter
```